# How to apply a python function to splitted 'from the end' pandas sub-dataframes and get a new dataframe?

Tags: python, function, pandas, numpy, split

### The problem

Starting from a pandas dataframe `df` made of `dim_df` rows, I need a new 
dataframe `df_new` obtained by **applying a function to every sub-dataframe** of dimension `dim_blk`, *ideally splitted starting from the last row (so the first block, not the last, may have or not the right number of rows, `dim_blk`)*, **in the most efficient way** (may be vectorized?).

### Example

In the following example the dataframe is made of few rows, but the real dataframe will be made of millions of rows, that's why I need an efficient solution.

```
dim_df = 7 # dimension of the starting dataframe
dim_blk = 3 # number of rows of the splitted block

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,dim_df+1), columns=['TEST'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   TEST
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
5     6
6     7
```

The splitted blocks I want:

```
1     # note: this is the first block composed by a <= dim_blk number of rows
2,3,4
5,6,7 # note: this is the last block and it has dim_blk number of rows
```

---

I've done so (*I don't know if this is the efficient way*):

```
lst = np.arange(dim_df, 0, -dim_blk) # [7 4 1]
lst_mod = lst[1:] # [4 1] to cut off the last empty sub-dataframe
split_df = np.array_split(df, lst_mod[::-1]) # splitted by reversed list
print(split_df)
```

Output:

```
split_df: [
   TEST
0     1,
   TEST
1     2
2     3
3     4,
   TEST
4     5
5     6
6     7]
```

For example:

```
print(split_df[1])
```

Output:

```
   TEST
1     2
2     3
3     4
```

---

**How can I get a new dataframe, `df_new`, where every row is made by two columns, `min` and `max`** (*just an example*) **calculated for every blocks?**

I.e:

```
# df_new

    Min   Max
0     1     1
1     2     4
2     5     7
```

Thank you,
Gilberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> ## The Solution
>
> I've think laterally and found a very speedy solution:
>
> 1. Apply a rolling function to the entire dataframe
> 2. Choose every `num_blk` rows starting from the end
>
> The code (with different values):
>
> ```
> import numpy as np
> import pandas as pd
> import time
>
> dim_df = 500000
> dim_blk = 240
>
> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,dim_df+1), columns=['TEST'])
>
> start_time = time.time()
>
> df['MAX'] = df['TEST'].rolling(dim_blk).max()
> df['MIN'] = df['TEST'].rolling(dim_blk).min()
>
> df[['MAX', 'MIN']] = df[['MAX', 'MIN']].fillna(method='bfill')
>
> df_split = pd.DataFrame(columns=['MIN', 'MAX'])
> df_split['MAX'] = df['MAX'][-1::-dim_blk][::-1]
> df_split['MIN'] = df['MIN'][-1::-dim_blk][::-1]
> df_split.reset_index(inplace=True)
> del(df_split['index'])
>
> print(df_split.tail())
>
> print('\n\nEND\n\n')
> print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
> ```
>
> ### Time Stats
>
> The original code stops after **545** secs. The new code stops after **0,16** secs. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `split_df` into dataframe and then create a dataframe using `min` and `max` functions i.e

```
split_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array_split(df['TEST'], lst_mod[::-1])) 

df_new = pd.DataFrame({"MIN":split_df.min(axis=1),"MAX":split_df.max(axis=1)}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   MAX  MIN
0  1.0  1.0
1  4.0  2.0
2  7.0  5.0
```